# Best way to store parameter that changes over the course of time

Tags: oracle, design-patterns, plsql, oracle11g, constraints

Consider the following scenario: 
We have a function (let's call it `service_cost`) that performs some sort of computations.

In that computations we also use a variable (say `current_fee`) witch has a certain value at a given time (we get the value of that variable from an  auxiliary table - `fee_table`).
Now `current_fee` could stay the same for 4 months, then it changes and obtains a new value, and so on and so forth. Of course I would like to know the current fee, but also should be able to find out the fee that was 'active' days, months, years before...

So, one way of organizing the the `fee_table` is

```
create table fee_table  (
 id number,
 valid_from date,
 valid_to date,
 fee number
)
```

And then at any given time - if I want to get the current fee I would:

```
    select fee into current_fee form 
    fee_table where trunc(sysdate) between valid_from and valid_to;
```

What I **don't like** about the solution above, is that it is easy to create inconsistent entries into `fee_table` - like:

-overlapping time periods (`valid_from`-`valid_to`) e.g. `(1/1/2012 - 1/2/2012) and (15/1/2012-5/2012)`

-no entry for current period

-holes in between the periods e.g. `([1/1/2012-1/2/2012],[1/4/2012-1/5/2012])`

etc.

Could anyone suggest a better way to handle such a scenario? 
Or may be - if we stick with the above scenario - some kind of constraints, check, triggers etc upon the table to avoid the inconsistencies described?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need the `valid_to` date - if a `valid_from` date implies the end of the previous entry, don't you just need to check that is unique, and the other problems go away?

Comment: This is generally referred to as "Slowly Changing Dimension". Your way of storing it is (in my opinion) the best way to do it. The trick is when loading this table with deltas that the load is managed properly to insure you don't end up with overlapping periods. That's a critical part to get right because overlapping time periods for your key field(s) causes duplicates. Some products help manage write and manage this code like [Oracles Warehouse Builder](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/owb/owb10gr2_gs/owb/lesson3/slowlychangingdimensions.htm)

Comment: This is a bit of an age-old question. One approach is to store only `start_date`, and compute `end_date` using a `lag() ` expression (perhaps in a view). Overlaps and gaps go away, but then every query requires a window sort. Or, you split the historical values off to a separate history table, so getting the current value is simple, but then you need two different queries. Or, you do that but you have a view combining current and historical versions with a `union all`. Or, use [Flashback Data Archive](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1).

Comment: Your approach is common.  Your app will be responsible for making sure there are no gaps or overlaps.  You could also keep one table for the current fee and keep the changes in a history tables like you’ve specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the comments above. So based on `@Alex Pool` and  `@William Robertson`.

I am leaning towards the following solution:

**The table**

```
create table fee_table  (
 id number unique,
 valid_from date unique,
 fee number
)
```

**The Data:**

```
insert into fee_table_todel(tid, valid_from,fee) values (1,to_date('1/1/2014','dd/mm/rrrr'), 30.5);
insert into fee_table_todel(tid, valid_from,fee) values (2,to_date('3/2/2014','dd/mm/rrrr'), 20.5);
insert into fee_table_todel(tid, valid_from,fee) values (3,to_date('4/4/2014','dd/mm/rrrr'), 10);
```

**The select:**

```
with from_to_table as (
    SELECT tid, valid_from,  LEAD(valid_from, 1, null) OVER (ORDER BY 
    valid_from)-1 AS valid_to,fee
    FROM   fee_table
    )
    select fee from from_to_table
    where to_date(:mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr')  between valid_from and nvl(valid_to,to_date(:mydate,'dd/mm/rrrr')+1)
```